# Making one header to be needed for several classes inclusion

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I have a number of classes and they are quite close to each other like

```
class A
{
//code
};

class B
{
   A* field;
//code
};

class C: public B
{
//code
};
```

And so on.
And I want to place them in a separate headers (`A.h`, `B.h`...) but to avoid adding every one of this header to projects I need a header like `myLib.h`, that will be just one needed header to include all the classes that I have wrote. Ho do I achieve it?

Also I think not to use `#pragma once;` and to make it working

```
#ifndef _MY_LIB_H
#define _MY_LIB_H
#endif
```

Where should I place it? In every header?

I've tried doing it like

```
class A;
class B;
...
```

in `myLib.h`

but then adding `myLib.h` to `main.cpp` is not enough to use A or B objects there. Also, in `B.h` that

```
#inlude myLib.h

void someMethod()
{
//field is instance of A
  this.field.otherMethod();
}
```

causes an error because methods of A are declared in `A.h`, not in `myLib.h`.

Sorry for long and tangled question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a separate include guard in each of `A.h`, `B.h`, `C.h`:

```
// Note: not a good name for a guard macro (too short)
#ifndef _A_H
#define _A_H
    // definition of A
#endif
```

And then `MyLib.h` becomes simply:

```
#include<A.h>
#include<B.h>
#include<C.h>
```

Of course each of your headers should manually include as many of the others as required so that it can stand alone (e.g. `C.h` would need to include `B.h` so that the code compiles if someone includes `C.h` directly).

In some cases you will not need to have one header include another because a forward declaration is enough -- for example in `B.h`, where an `A*` member is declared:

```
#ifndef _B_H
#define _B_H
class A;

class B
{
   A* field;
};
#endif
```

Comment: Also you can avoid some inclusions by using forward declarations.

Comment: @EdHeal: Thanks for the input, updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: Strictly speaking, names like `_A...` are reserved for the implementation, it's probably better to choose a different convention for header guards. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Answer (score 2):

Besides using the pattern

```
#ifndef _A_H
#define _A_H

   ... Stuffs

#endif
```

in each header, I always add

```
#ifndef _A_H
#include <A.h>
#endif
#ifndef _B_H
#include <B.h>
#endif
....
```

to other headers, like `myLib.h`. This considerably improves the speed of compilation because compiler does not need to load and scan the low level headers if they are already scanned.

I do not add this to my cpp files, because the number of headers in cpp is typically reasonable, while it mich more difficult to track relations between headers.